# Multiple invoice line in excel report in ODOO 13

Tags: odoo, reporting, invoice

I am creating this excel report for vat summary for every invoice lines

In an invoice there can be more than one invoice line/journal item

for the same I used the below code

if len(invoice.invoice_line_ids) > 1:

worksheet.write(row, 3, invoice.invoice_line_ids[0].product_id.name)

for product_id in invoice.invoice_line_ids[1:]:

row += 1

worksheet.write(row, 3, product_id.name)

else:

worksheet.write(row, 3, invoice.invoice_line_ids[0].product_id.name)

for a product name its coming correctly

but when I copy the same code for other fields such as VAT name, price subtotal etc  its showing as in the image
[report sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QP6G0.png)

Please check out my full code

**#code for Product name which is correct**

if len(invoice.invoice_line_ids) > 1:

worksheet.write(row, 3, invoice.invoice_line_ids[0].product_id.name)

for product_id in invoice.invoice_line_ids[1:]:

row += 1

worksheet.write(row, 3, product_id.name)

else:

worksheet.write(row, 3, invoice.invoice_line_ids[0].product_id.name)

**#code for vat name which is not correct**

if len(invoice.invoice_line_ids) > 1:

worksheet.write(row, 4, invoice.invoice_line_ids[0].tax_ids.name)

for tax_ids in invoice.invoice_line_ids[1:]:

row += 1

worksheet.write(row, 4, tax_ids.name)

else:

worksheet.write(row, 4, invoice.invoice_line_ids.tax_ids.name)

**#code for subtotal which is not correct**

if len(invoice.invoice_line_ids) > 1:

```
 worksheet.write(row, 5, str(invoice.invoice_line_ids[0].price_subtotal))

 for price_subtotal in invoice.invoice_line_ids[1:]:

     row += 1

     worksheet.write(row, 5, str(price_subtotal))
```

else:

```
 worksheet.write(row, 5, str(invoice.invoice_line_ids.price_subtotal))
```

Comment: Please add the proper identation you your code, every single line of code should start with 4 spaces of identation. I will check it out again after that. BTW invoice.invoice_line_ids.tax_ids its a recorset you should use a for each value of tax_ids

Comment: When you loop over `invoice.invoice_line_ids`, price_subtotal is a reference to an invoice line, you could use `for line in invoice.invoice_line_ids: line.price_subtotal`

Comment: You should edit the question properly! Remember that users that want to help you, don't need not want to spend more time than necessary trying to UNDERSTAND the question. And if it's not readable, it's hard for them to come with a quick answer for you! For coding, for example, you can copy and paste the code, select all of it and press 'ctrl+k'. It will format it properly into the code format.